slurm - is it possible to query slurmctld/slurmd to know if they are using the right slurm.conf version?
I am facing a problem where slurmctld and slurmd are not in sync in terms of using the same slurm.conf file so we have this:
error: Node node1 appears to have a different slurm.conf than the slurmctld.  This could cause issues with communication and functionality.  Please review both files and make sure they are the same.  If this is expected ignore, and set DebugFlags=NO_CONF_HASH in your slurm.conf.
error: Node node2 appears to have a different slurm.conf than the slurmctld.  This could cause issues with communication and functionality.  Please review both files and make sure they are the same.  If this is expected ignore, and set DebugFlags=NO_CONF_HASH in your slurm.conf.
error: Node node3 appears to have a different slurm.conf than the slurmctld.  This could cause issues with communication and functionality.  Please review both files and make sure they are the same.  If this is expected ignore, and set DebugFlags=NO_CONF_HASH in your slurm.conf.
error: Node node4 appears to have a different slurm.conf than the slurmctld.  This could cause issues with communication and functionality.  Please review both files and make sure they are the same.  If this is expected ignore, and set DebugFlags=NO_CONF_HASH in your slurm.conf.

Is there a way (other than parsing log errors) to query slurmctld/slurmd individualy about the configs they are running on to know if any of them has to be restarted or reconfigured? Getting a hash should be enough to compare them against each other, I would assume.
update: also knowing the time that slurm.conf file was read would be handy.

I would suggest using configless in the slurm conf. You will still get the error messages in the slurm logs when the daemons start up but they can be safely ignored. All slurmd systems will pull the proper config from the slurm controller.

This is interesting for sure..... But I would still like to be able to query each item to know if they are using the latest and greatest (not to name coolest, of course) config available or if they are using an old one.

@eftshift0 You can query each client using scontrol show config and diff the output with the controller's version to confirm that they're the same. Or you can wait 20-30 seconds and be assured that the clients are using the most current config. The configless option was set up to handle exactly the case you're concerned with. Why re-invent the wheel?
